# How do I get the value of the jdbc.batch_size property at runtime for a Web application using Spring MVC and Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring

According to what I have found so far, I can use the following code:

```
    LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = (LocalSessionFactoryBean)super.getApplicationContext().getBean("&sessionFactory");
    System.out.println(sessionFactory.getConfiguration().buildSettings().getJdbcBatchSize());
```

but then I get a Hibernate Exception:

> org.hibernate.HibernateException: No local DataSource found for
>   configuration - dataSource property must be set on
>   LocalSessionFactoryBean

Can somebody shed some light?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following (I can't test it since I don't use Spring):

```
System.out.println(sessionFactory.getConfiguration().getProperty("hibernate.jdbc.batch_size"))
```

Answer (score 4):

On the versions of Hibernate that I've checked, getConfiguration is not a public method of SessionFactory.  In a few desperate cases, I've cast a Session or SessionFactory into its underlying implementation to get at some values that weren't publicly available.  In this case that would be:

```
((SessionFactoryImplementor)sessionFactory).getSettings().getJdbcBatchSize()
```

Of course, that's dangerous because it could break if they change the implementation. I usually only do this for optimizations that I can live without and then wrap the whole thing in a try/catch Throwable block just to make sure it won't hurt anything if it fails. A better idea might be to set the value yourself when you initialize Hibernate so you already know what it is from the beginning.

Comment: Note that the sessionFactory variable in the question is not an instance of Hibernate's SessionFactory; it's of LocalSessionFactoryBean, which is a Spring class.